# Saving the output of each iteration of a for loop into a different df in r

Tags: r

I have a df that looks something like:

```
structure(list(id = c(20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 
20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 
20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 
20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 
20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 
20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 
20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 
20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 
20230426, 20230426), condition = c("control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", "forced_break", 
"forced_break", "forced_break"), `total scores` = c(4.1, 4.1, 
4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 
4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 
4.1, 4.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 
5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 
5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 
2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 
2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 
2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 
2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 
2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 
2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 
2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667, 2.76666666666667
), round = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
"22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30"), win = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), sound = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 1, 4, 8, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 
8, 8, 8, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 2, 5, 7, 4, 7, 6, 8, 5, 1, 8, 5, 3, 
7, 6, 3, 6, 6, 5, 5, 8, 1, 6, 6, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 6, 7, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 8, 8, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5
), ttrs = c(34.8679761886597, 53.7323212623596, 72.872288942337, 
95.00337266922, 108.467720985413, 127.519412279129, 140.932771205902, 
152.619723320007, 164.774888753891, 189.440443992615, 199.848607540131, 
211.736871480942, 228.6589448452, 240.730955839157, 258.806998729706, 
272.826892614365, 285.802761793137, 301.402906894684, 314.37718629837, 
330.579266309738, 342.812170028686, 353.819888830185, 370.405727863312, 
379.25874209404, 386.349495410919, 398.328526258469, 408.155629873276, 
420.099550485611, 430.813805341721, 441.291796922684, 29.6801872253418, 
61.7878353595734, 89.5833258628845, 112.175926685333, 136.321815729141, 
159.805800199509, 181.024982452393, 204.576705217361, 229.754760742187, 
252.246057987213, 278.35747718811, 301.428213357925, 331.172312736511, 
357.232907295227, 382.993041753769, 407.828387975693, 431.264756441116, 
459.867380857468, 487.130186796188, 512.275333881378, 536.979578495026, 
562.144499540329, 587.272258758545, 606.266097545624, 627.859202861786, 
646.82401394844, 675.076813459397, 695.227046489715, 722.417305469513, 
746.061215877533, 24.1262958049774, 46.1197996139526, 69.595000743866, 
91.7691426277161, 113.158320903778, 138.003797292709, 155.998581647873, 
177.223141670227, 201.188986063004, 224.860546827316, 247.949486255646, 
267.901841878891, 291.57377743721, 314.699640989304, 331.995548725128, 
357.073381185532, 374.627980947494, 394.242617845535, 416.460289239883, 
440.999413728714, 460.512001037598, 478.17138171196, 497.328444957733, 
519.576447248459, 542.862848997116, 565.327050447464, 585.403351068497, 
602.992196559906, 628.106581926346, 646.194223165512), ttbp = c(42.8691244125366, 
57.7340142726898, 79.8788452148437, 101.018859148026, 114.473237752914, 
130.520850658417, 144.944416761398, 158.633060216904, 173.786515951157, 
193.448391675949, 203.859516382217, 220.743315935135, 233.666549682617, 
249.745782613754, 265.810203790665, 278.836834669113, 291.811623334885, 
302.416656732559, 320.388904809952, 335.58996462822, 347.819845914841, 
361.828748226166, 372.408302783966, 380.263983488083, 390.360696315765, 
402.329761266708, 411.160075902939, 425.111953496933, 435.816273927689, 
450.295118093491, 33.6942596435547, 67.7940876483917, 90.5839512348175, 
116.175999641418, 138.333419799805, 157.814015626907, 182.028251886368, 
207.588495731354, 232.764085531235, 258.256726026535, 281.364413261414, 
305.43529343605, 337.185777664185, 361.246183633804, 387.001929998398, 
411.83786034584, 437.275370597839, 465.873136758804, 492.145275831223, 
517.284260034561, 541.986734867096, 567.157546281814, 587.27401804924, 
606.26666021347, 627.865776538849, 652.831952571869, 673.082495212555, 
699.235440015793, 726.420786142349, 746.065225839615, 24.1314544677734, 
49.1218030452728, 72.6030163764953, 93.7751977443695, 119.166162490845, 
137.005982160568, 158.001306533814, 182.226684093475, 206.202028751373, 
228.862356901169, 247.94946885109, 271.908250331879, 295.585940599442, 
313.710790157318, 337.003004789352, 356.078580141068, 375.63186955452, 
397.245104789734, 422.463978052139, 441.012653827667, 459.525042533875, 
479.177524328232, 501.342493057251, 523.58589553833, 544.876298427582, 
567.328588247299, 584.410531997681, 608.997703313828, 626.115336179733, 
644.19508767128), ttbi = c(50.7323212623596, 69.872288942337, 
92.00337266922, 105.467720985413, 124.519412279129, 137.932771205902, 
149.619723320007, 161.774888753891, 186.440443992615, 196.848607540131, 
208.736871480942, 225.6589448452, 237.730955839157, 255.806998729706, 
269.826892614365, 282.802761793137, 298.402906894684, 311.37718629837, 
327.579266309738, 339.811122179031, 350.818850278854, 367.405727863312, 
376.25874209404, 383.348484039307, 395.328526258469, 405.155629873276, 
417.099550485611, 427.813805341721, 438.291796922684, 454.063094377518, 
61.7867980003357, 89.5833258628845, 112.175926685333, 136.321815729141, 
159.804799079895, 181.024982452393, 204.576705217361, 229.754760742187, 
252.246057987213, 278.35747718811, 301.428213357925, 331.172312736511, 
357.232907295227, 382.993041753769, 407.828387975693, 431.263774394989, 
459.867380857468, 487.130186796188, 512.275333881378, 536.979578495026, 
562.144499540329, 587.272258758545, 606.266097545624, 627.859202861786, 
646.82401394844, 675.076813459397, 695.227046489715, 722.417305469513, 
746.061215877533, 765.303467273712, 46.1197996139526, 69.595000743866, 
91.7691426277161, 113.158320903778, 138.003797292709, 155.998581647873, 
177.223141670227, 201.188986063004, 224.860546827316, 247.949486255646, 
267.901841878891, 291.57377743721, 314.699640989304, 331.995548725128, 
357.073381185532, 374.627980947494, 394.242617845535, 416.460289239883, 
440.999413728714, 460.511017084122, 478.17138171196, 497.328444957733, 
519.576447248459, 542.862848997116, 565.326538562775, 585.403351068497, 
602.992196559906, 628.106581926346, 646.194223165512, 662.426118850708
)), row.names = c(NA, 90L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Appologies for how long that it, but it is only a very small portion of what I am working with.

I am trying to create a new df for each id in a for loop. When I use:

```
ids <- unique(df_long$id)

for (i in 1:length(ids)){
  pair_standin <- subset(df_long, id == ids[i])
  print(pair_standin)
}
```

I get a print out of all the data I want, clearly seperatd by each itteration (great). But I cannot figure out how to get the loop to produce a new df for each id without having to create empy vectors for all ids manually outside of the loop. I want somthing like:

```
for (i in 1:length(ids)){
  pair_standin <- subset(df_long, id == ids[i])
  pair[i] <- pair_standin
}
```

Where the dfs are called pair{id number}. My expected output (with the above section of data) would be three dfs, each 30x9 and called pair20230420, pair20230424, and pair20230426. I think I must be getting the `pair[i]` notation wrong but I can't seem to find answers online. I would expect  `pair{i}` to work (as in python), but r does not seem to know what to do with "{}"

Note that with:

```
pair <- matrix(nrow = 30, ncol = 9)

for (i in 1:length(ids)){
  pair_standin <- subset(df_long, id == ids[i])
  print(pair_standin)
  pair <- as.data.frame(pair_standin)
}
```

I get just the last itteration (as you'd expect from the above)... How do I get the loop to make a new df for each interaction rather than overriding the single df?

Comment: Maybe use `pair <- split(df_long, df_long$id)` ?

Comment: That gives me a list that looks like it contains all the info I need. How do I split the list into different dfs?

Comment: You can access those with `pair[[1]]`, `pair[[2]]`, ... Or with their name `pair[["name"]]`. Alternatively `list2env(pair)` will bring them to your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for base r `assign` function

```r
ids <- unique(df_long$id)
for (i in 1:length(ids)){
  pair_standin <- subset(df_long, id == ids[i])
  #print(pair_standin)
  pair <- as.data.frame(pair_standin)
  assign(paste0("pair_",ids[i]),pair)
}

head(pair_20230420)
#>         id condition total scores round win sound      ttrs      ttbp      ttbi
#> 1 20230420   control          4.1     1   1     1  34.86798  42.86912  50.73232
#> 2 20230420   control          4.1     2   0     1  53.73232  57.73401  69.87229
#> 3 20230420   control          4.1     3   1     2  72.87229  79.87885  92.00337
#> 4 20230420   control          4.1     4   1     1  95.00337 101.01886 105.46772
#> 5 20230420   control          4.1     5   1     2 108.46772 114.47324 124.51941
#> 6 20230420   control          4.1     6   1     1 127.51941 130.52085 137.93277
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>